# Synonyms map for the Azure Cognitive Search Suggestion

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm Trying to implement synonyms map for the Suggest.
Eg: Mt -> Mount
This is perfectly working with Azure Search.
But not working with Azure Suggest.
Does anyone know this is a limitation with Cognitive search or is there a way to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know this is a limitation with Cognitive search or is
> there a way to achieve?

Synonym maps are not supported for Suggesters. From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms#how-synonyms-are-used-during-query-execution):

> *Synonyms apply to free form text queries only and are not supported
> for filters, facets, autocomplete, or suggestions. **Autocomplete and
> suggestions are based only on the original term; synonym matches do
> not appear in the response.***

Comment: I see this post from 2021 & now its 2024 still Synonym map is not supported for suggestions. I have created a idea. Please vote so that MS takes it up: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/65c90634-09e1-ee11-a73d-0022484c4e0d